# In python: how to ignore errors beyond quit()

Tags: python, error-handling, exit

Motivation: often I'm testing code on the fly (testing as I write the code, in other words).  I am well aware of errors that lie ahead, but I only want to run the code up until the `quit()` line which I know has no errors, and ignore the ignore any errors beyond the quit() line, which will be dealt with later.

Unfortunately, any errors beyond `quit()` prevent me from running the code at all.

I need a way to say to python, "just run the code up until `quit()` and don't worry about what comes later".

How can I achieve this?  I have no particular attachment to `quit()`.  If another function would achieve the same, then that is acceptable to me.

Comment: Maybe use a debugger? With a breakpoint on the `quit()`

Comment: @rdas noted as an alternative, thank you, but would still rather be able to do it without a debugger, whilst I am writing the code

Comment: Replace `quit()` with `input()`? So that python waits for something to be typed in?

Comment: @rdas python is still objecting to the errors that lie ahead when I use `input()`?

Comment: You can ad some logic like: "if you type in 'q' the program will exit, otherwise continue with the rest of the program"

Comment: @rdas I still pine for something equivalent to PHP's `exit`, which doesn't care about errors ahead

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither debugger breakpoint nor quit() can solve the "syntax" or indentation error beyond the breakpoint or quit() line.

The best strategy may be just comment out those code you don't want to deal with.

For example, the following code has indentation error beyond quit() line. You won't be able to run without fixing it:

```
x,y = 1,2
z = x+y
print(z)
quit()
#code you don't want to deall with for now
#and my have bugs in it below
if t > 0 :
print(t)
```

When run it, you will encounter following error:

```
  File "/home/paul/test/quit.py", line 8
    print(t)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

If you comment out the lines after quit(), then it will work as you want:

```
x,y = 1,2
z = x+y
print(z)
quit()
#code you don't want to deall with for now
#and my have bugs in it below
'''
if t > 0 :
print(t)
'''
```

or

```
x,y = 1,2
z = x+y
print(z)
quit()
# #code you don't want to deall with for now
# #and my have bugs in it below
# if t > 0 :
# print(t)
```